# How to make the articles 90% height of the site

Tags: html, css

I have one section and in it three sections:

```
 <section id="home">

 <article id="rechts">
<h1>Übersicht</h1>
 </article>
 <article id="mitte">
<h1>Leute</h1>
 </article>
 <article id="links">
<h1>Links</h1>
 </article>

 </section>
```

I tried to make the articles 90% of the height of the site. SO i appended 100% height to body, and section. And of course i gave the articales a height of 90%.
But somehow it didnt worked. I know there are very easy solutions with jquery but i want to use css thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/g6JyD/

My css:

```
body { width:100%;
    background-color:#ecf0f1;
    height: 100%; }

section { width: 90%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 90%
     }

article {
    width:29%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    float: left;
    margin: 5% 2% 10% 2%;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

#rechts {
    background-color: #9b59b6
}

#mitte {
   background-color:  #16a085;
}

#links {
    background-color: #f1c40f;
}
```

Comment: Note: it's more logical to have your first element to be `links` and the last one `rechts`. For instance, when displaying the articles inline, the first one will be displayed at the left.

Comment: You need to explicitly set height to all tags, so `<html>` needs to have a height also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's add `height: 100%` also to `html`:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**[Now it works!](http://jsfiddle.net/g6JyD/1/)**

Hey, there's still something wrong. Some margins are spoiling the layout. We'll fix it by *resetting* the `body` default margin and padding

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Now the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6JyD/4/)** rocks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix this but you said

> I tried to make the articles 90% of the height of the site. SO i appended 100% height to body, and section. And of course i gave the articales a height of 90%.

When in fact in your css you gave the section 90% and the articles 100%

```
section { width: 90%;
margin: 0px auto;
height: 90%
}

article {
width:29%;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
float: left;
margin: 5% 2% 10% 2%;
padding: 0px;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you add the correct positioning to the

```
<section>
```

element. Here's a corrected [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andRyanMiller/g6JyD/3/). And my corrected CSS for your section element:

```
section { 
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
        background-color:red;
     }
```

The reasoning for this is simple: only properly positioned elements will allow their children to inherit height and width attributes.